# Publish Angular 5.2 Server Side Rendering to IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, server-side-rendering

I have created an Angular 5.2.0 App using Visual Studio Code and using Server-side rendering in the project. The Angular project runs fine and builds as well. To start server-side rendering we normally use the command - `node dist/server.js` which starts the Express engine and runs the project.

I would like to know how can I add this production build in an existing ASP.Net application (**NOT** using ASP.Net Core) so that the angular app runs along with the ASP.NET application.

Any help is appreciated.